# How to use language files in plugins?

Tags: multi-language

At the moment i'm developing my first wordpress plugin and want to include multi-language function in it. May be there is some manuals on it? Tried to google, but only get `best wordpress language switcher plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically read the source for the function `load_plugin_textdomain()`:

```
function load_plugin_textdomain( $domain, $abs_rel_path = false, $plugin_rel_path = false )
```

Ignore the second parameter, it was deprecated a long time ago.

An example from my plugin [T5 Taxonomy Location](https://github.com/toscho/t5-taxonomy-location):

```
protected function load_language()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain(
        'plugin_t5_tax_location',
        FALSE,
        plugin_basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages'
    );
}
```

The first parameter is the text domain, the last the path to the `languages` directory in the plugin.

Now you can use strings in your plugin with that text domain:

```
__( 'Locations', 'plugin_t5_tax_location' )
```

There are multiple tools available to create new translations. I have used [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) in the past, but it is broken now unfortunately.

Comment: What is wrong here:

`function load_language(){
 load_plugin_textdomain('dleToWp', FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )).'/languages/'); 
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_language');

add_management_page(__('Title', 'dleToWp'), __('Convert database', 'dleToWp'), 'manage_options', 'database_convert', array($this, 'settings_page'));`

`wp-content/plugins/dleToWP/languages/ru_RU.mo`

Comment: Maybe the trailing slash?

Comment: And second question, how do you manage to use protect method? I jus added in to the constructor `  add_action('plugins_loaded', array($this, 'load_language'));
` and it fails

Comment: I am calling this method in my constructor. See the source code of the plugin.

Comment: i am not so well in both oop and wordpress, but may be you can give small tip if this line possible `add_action('init', array('myClass', 'constructor'));`

Comment: No, it is not. Use a `get_instance()` like I do.

Comment: but i don't really need it... So i think i just leave it with `new...`